# How can I fix a workspace switcher freeze?

Tags: command-line, unity, workspaces

A few minutes ago when using workspace switcher, it froze as I tried to slide a window from one screen to another with the GUI interface. As a result, the whole screen was frozen and I couldn't get back out of the 4-screen layout shown when switching workspaces.

I could open a terminal, but didn't know what to do with it to get out of this. What should I do if it comes up again?

(There was a rather high load on the graphics card when this happened. Or maybe it was just a rare glitch. I would like to keep using the workspace switcher as I need two copies of Blender, a bunch of browser tabs, and a few images open right now.)

(I had to shut down to get out of this. If I'd had something unsaved, that could have been a real pain.)

Comment: Alright, it just happened again, so there is a larger issue here...

Comment: Kim, it's a bug. I've seen it myself. It seems to happen when I slide a terminal window diagonally. It seems to happen less if I drag left/right/up/down. If you can get to terminal, you can restart lightdm. It'll blast you out of your login, but at least you won't have to force shutdown and reboot. Cheers, Al